# Parse.com not return the data from the table?

Tags: parse-platform

I want to Query the data from the table on parse collection.

This my code

```
  var DummyObject = Parse.Object.extend("dummyFlow2");
  var dummyObject = new DummyObject();
  var query = new Parse.Query(DummyObject);
  query.equalTo("oneT", 280);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
        // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
        console.log(results);
        console.log(results[0]);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
```

But i only got the id of the data not the content of it like this

[image]

This is some data from my class

[image]

So how can i get the rest of the data?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try accessing it instead of just debugging?

Answer (score 1):

try this to get the contents:
Basically if you want to access data from parse object then data is stored with attributes and element name

> EX as follows:
>
> to get MF:

`results[0].attributes.MF`

> to get id:

`results[0].id`

> to get fiveHundred:

`results[0].attributes.fiveHundred`